# Bootstrap Navbar Customization(s)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a very simple `Bootstrap Navbar` that I am trying to do a little customization to. All I want to do is to pull the title all the left and for the 3 choices `Home` `Menu 1` and `Menu 2` to be pulled all the way right. I have tried to add `pull-left` and `pull-right` to my inline styling, but believe it is being over written.... Can anyone tell me how I can accomplish this? I will post image and markup below:

The image is what I currently have, not what I am trying to accomplish. The markup is my existing HTML.

[image]

**Markup**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="margin-bottom: -5px !important;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Title</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>              
            <li runat="server" class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 1<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> 3</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i> 4</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>                               
            <li runat="server" class="dropdown">                  
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> 1</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> 2</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> 3</a></li>                                          
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `navbar-right` for your links and if you want them as far to the left and right on the screen use `container-fluid` instead of `container`.

See example Snippet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Title</a>

    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li runat="server" class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 1<b class="caret"></b></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> 3</a>

            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i> 4</a>

            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> 5</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li runat="server" class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 2<b class="caret"></b></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> 1</a>

            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> 2</a>

            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> 3</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: No problem and glad I could help.